# Showing this integral is zero

Tags: integration, fourier-series, bessel-functions

Given $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, it is said in an article that the Fourier series of the function $\exp\big(ir \sin(kt)\big)$ is
$$ \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^\infty J_m(r) e^{imkt},$$
where $J_m(r)$ is the Bessel integral
$$ J_m(r) := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ir \sin(\theta)}e^{-im\theta}\; d\theta.$$

If I'm not mistaken this means that the $mk$-th Fourier coefficient ($m \in \mathbb{Z}$) of the function $\exp\big(ir \sin(kt)\big)$ is $J_m(r)$ and the other Fourier coefficients (those that are not multiples of $k$) are zero.

Using a change of variable, I could show that the $mk$-th Fourier coefficient of the function $\exp\big(ir \sin(kt)\big)$ is $J_m(r)$. However I'm unable to show that the others are zero.

How do we show that the following integral is zero for all $m \not\in k \mathbb{Z}$ ?

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ir \sin(kt)}e^{-imt}\; dt.$$

Comment: The article is of no help here as this is stated as a fact.

Comment: (sorry mistake) this is the Fourier series theorem : $f(t) = e^{i r \sin(kt)}$ is obviously $2\pi / k$ periodic whenever $r,k \in \mathbb{R}$. It is also $C^1$ (and $C^\infty$) Hence $f(t) = \sum_{m = - \infty}^\infty c_m e^{i  m  kt}$ where $c_m = \frac{1}{2\pi / k} \int_0^{2 \pi / k} e^{- i m   kt } f(t) dt$ and the series converges uniformly, and this trigonometric series is the only one converging to $f(t)$